# Let $(\mathbb{X},p)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Then $(A^{\circ})^{\circ} = A^{\circ}$

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

I'm homelearning calculus and trying to verify whether the following statement is true or not:

> Let $(\mathbb{X},p)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Then
>   $(A^{\circ})^{\circ} = A^{\circ}$

However, I'm really sure how should I approach the problem. $A^{\circ}$ is the set of all interior points of set $A$.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $(A^{\circ})^{\circ} \subset A^{\circ}$. Let $a \in  A^{\circ}$. By definition of $ A^{\circ}$, there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(a) \subset  A^{\circ}$. Thus, $a \in ( A^{\circ})^{\circ}$. Therefore, $ A^{\circ} \subset (A^{\circ})^{\circ} .$